# Python lru_cache: how can currsize < misses < maxsize?

Tags: python, caching, lru

I have a class with a method that is annotated with the [`lru_cache` annotation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache):

```
CACHE_SIZE=16384

class MyClass:
    [...]

    @lru_cache(maxsize=CACHE_SIZE)
    def _my_method(self, texts: Tuple[str]):
       <some heavy text processing>

    def cache_info(self):
        return self._my_method.cache_info()
```

After running for a while, I look at the cache statistics through the `cache_info()` method:

```
c = MyClass()
[...]
c.cache_info()

{
  "hits":9348,
  "misses":4312,
  "maxsize":16384,
  "currsize":2588
}
```

My question is: how can `currsize` be smaller than `misses` AND smaller than `maxsize`?

My understanding *was*: for each miss, the result is added to the cache, hence increasing the current size. Only when the current size has reached the maximum size, cached results are removed. Since the maximum size is not reached here yet, each miss should be cached, so `currsize` should equal `misses` at this point.
However, that does not seem to be the way this works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your program is either multi-threaded, or recursive - basically, any sort of condition where `_my_method()` might be called again while another call is partially completed - then it's possible to see the behavior you're experiencing.

`lru_cache()` is thread-aware and uses the following set of steps for size-limited caching:

- make a hash key out of the wrapped function's arguments
- lock the cache in a `with` block:

  - look up the key in the cache
  - if the key is in the cache, return the cached value
  - else, if the key isn't in the cache, increase `misses` by 1
- call the wrapped function
- lock the cache again

  - if the result is in the cache now, return it
  - if the result still isn't in the cache, add it, possibly removing older entries, etc. etc.

In other words, the cached value may have been added by another thread while the wrapped function was called, but it's still counted as a miss. If you had multiple calls to `_my_method()` that looked up the same missing key, causing `misses` to be incremented but then resulting in the key appearing in the cache by the time `_my_method()` completes, `misses` will be higher than `currsize`.

Comment: This explanation sounds very likely, thanks! The class is running within a service using multiple threads indeed, so that requests to the cache could come in in parallel.